# Select component in form.io is showing an extra textbox at the bottom

Tags: angularjs, forms, api

I am new in form.io. I created a registration page containing textboxes and select controls. This page is embedded into my application. In the preview everything is shown fine,but after embedding in my page,a textbox is shown at the bottom of every select control.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. I missed the css formio-complete.min.css.